# how to use pointer to operator in member functions?

Tags: c++, operators, pointer-to-member

i am trying to change a code from regular functions to "Member function pointers" everything work fine but i have no idea how to define the pointer to operator

before the main i wrote

```
typedef int*(tArray_t<int>::*op)(int)const;
```

then inside the main

```
int main(){
//...
op oper=&tArray_t<int>::operator[];


    cout<<*intArray[2]<<endl;   // how do i change it here ?????????? 
//...

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a toy example using operator ! and a member pointer to it, looks like VC++ 10 was ok with it:

```
class Test
{
public:
    bool operator !() {return true;};   
};

typedef bool (Test::* memfunptr)();

int main(){

Test tt;
memfunptr mf = &Test::operator!;

bool res = (tt.*mf)();

return 0;
}
```

So, try something along the lines of:

```
tArray_t intArray;
(intArray.*insert)(&((intArray.*op)(1)));
```

(Not sure what your actual definitions of intArray and insert are, so I'm guessing here that intArray is an instance and insert is another member ptr)

Answer (score 0):

```
    tArray_t<int> intArray;
```

i have changed this

```
*intArray[2]
```

with this , now it works , thx :)

```
(*(intArray.*oper)(2))
```